# HTML Visible On TYPO3 Extension Front End

Tags: html, forms, typo3, markers

I have created an extension in TYPO3. I want an HTML form in my front end. I have created a `textarea` field in my HTML template as follows:

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="50" id=""></textarea>
```

But the problem is that it is showing this same code `<textarea rows="10" cols="50" id=""></textarea>` directly on my front end page.

How can I solve this??
Rest of all Html parts are displaying correctly.

My code is as follows:-

```
     $markerArray['###OPTION_USERS###'].='<form action="'.$this->username().'" id="messageform" name="messageform" method="post">';
     $markerArray['###OPTION_USERS###'].='<textarea rows="10" cols="50" id=""></textarea><select id="selectedusers" name="selectedusers[]" size="" multiple="multiple">';

             while ($row = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($res)){
                    $markerArray['###OPTION_USERS###'].='<option value="'.$row['username'].'">'.$row['username'].'</option>';
             }
     $markerArray['###OPTION_USERS###'].='</select><input type="submit" name="sendmessage" value="send message"></form>';
```

Comment: What about the rest of the html part in the template? form tag, input tag etc. displayed correctly? Also please copy-paste the php part related to it.

Comment: rest all html parts are displaying correctly

Comment: I can't find any problem. Please copy-paste the current html output also.

Comment: Problem solved. I have forgot to include textarea into allowtags                 allowlib.parseFunc_RTE.allowTags := addToList(form, fieldset, input, select, option, label,textarea)